# ASP.NET content page: how to run a script on "body" with "body onload=myfunc()"

Tags: asp.net, javascript

i've added to the master page my script "myscript.js". 
Then, in a content page, i would like to load myscript() at startup (body onload).

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use

[Page.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx)

```
  if (!IsStartupScriptRegistered (key))
  {
      String script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" +
        "alert('Hello World');</" + "script>";
      RegisterStartupScript(key, script);
  }
```

Or you could use the JQuery library and add the function call to the document.ready function

http://jquery.com/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   // Add your function call here

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

this will add onload client side event to the master page's body tag:

in the master page:

```
body id="PageBody" runat="server"

in the content page:

HtmlGenericControl body = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("PageBody");

body.Attributes.Add("onload", "doSomething();");`
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a `ContentPlaceHolder` in the master-page for this purpose. This makes it possible to include specific scripts in the `<head>` only when you want it.

Answer (score 0):

The form has onLoad event. So use the  tag in your Masterpage

Comment: i don't want to use it in a masterpage to avoid run the script in other pages where it'snt necessary..

Comment: So why not Page.RegisterStartupScript or Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock?

Answer (score 0):

**Assign id and server="runnat" in master page body tag**

```
<body runat="server" id="body_master">
```

**Then your aspx .CS file insert below code in pageLoad event**

```
    HtmlGenericControl body = this.Master.FindControl("body_master") as HtmlGenericControl;

body.Attributes.Add("onLoad", "SessionTimeOuts();");
```

**SessionTimeOuts() function should be defined in your .aspx file**

Thank you